# Optaplanner skipping Phases and returning empty solution

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, optaplanner

I'm working on scheduling project for classes (Teachers, Lessons, time). I'm using optaplanner as part of spring-boot application, the test code is compiling and running correctly however the result contain empty solution, in the log output I see this message:

> rted: time spent (11), best score (0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
> 2021-09-28 22:39:26.619  INFO 2579 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver       : Skipped all phases (2): out of 0 planning entities, none are movable (non-pinned).
> 2021-09-28 22:39:26.620  INFO 2579 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver       : Solving ended: time spent (16), best score (0hard/0soft), score calculation speed (62/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).

The problem is in the test calculator I wrote I'm trying to loop on the possible solution and actually decrease the cost a bit sometimes or even increase it, but it doesn't taking effect because I'm looping and trying to log the objects but nothing is being logged, this is the code of the calculator:

```
public class ScheduleScoreCalculator implements EasyScoreCalculator<ScheduleTable, HardSoftScore>
{
@Override
public HardSoftScore calculateScore(ScheduleTable scheduleTable) {
    int hardScore = 0;
    int softScore = 0;

    List<ScheduledClass> scheduledClassList = scheduleTable.getScheduledClasses();
    System.out.println(scheduleTable);
    System.out.println("Hmmmmm ---"); // this is logged but the score is not changing
    for(ScheduledClass a: scheduledClassList) {
        for (ScheduledClass b : scheduledClassList) {
            if (a.getTeacher().getTeacherId() > 17000L) {
                hardScore+=18;
            }
            if (a.getTimeslot() != null && a.getTimeslot().equals(b.getTimeslot())
                    && a.getId() < b.getId()) {
                if (a.getTeacher() != null && a.getTeacher().equals(b.getTeacher())) {
                    hardScore--;
                }
                if (a.getTeacher().equals(b.getTeacher())) {
                    hardScore--;
                }
            } else {
                hardScore++;
                softScore+=2;
            }
        }
    }

    return HardSoftScore.of(hardScore, softScore);
}
}
```

So Please any idea why optaplanner might skip creating possible solutions?

Comment: The answer is right there in the log: "Skipped all phases (2): out of 0 planning entities, none are movable (non-pinned)." You appear to have no planning entities, therefore there is nothing to plan. I will leave it to you to check that your planning solution is properly annotated, and that it indeed includes some entities. if that is so and you are still seeing this issue, please share more information about your problem incl. your domain.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Your theory looks reasonable, I of course have @ PlanningEntity annotated class with 3 Planning variables, I tested your idea by removing the @ PlanningEntity but the project refused to build saying this:
"Maybe your @ PlanningEntity annotated class(es)  are not in a subpackage ..." so it is indeed seeing the Class with the annotation. However, maybe the structure is wrong, so I'll revise this, and if it didn't help I'll update the question details, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue was simpler than I thought, The Solution class annotated with "PlanningSolution" has property "scheduledClasses" annotated with "PlanningEntityCollectionProperty" my mistake that this property was initialized with empty List (ArrayList), the solution was to initialize a solution class! In retrospect I think the documentation is to be blamed on this, the [provided example](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.11.1.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#_create_the_solver_service) didn't mention that we need to have this, so it should not be null (otherwise and exception will be raised) and it shouldn't be empty List. You need to initialize it with class without setting any value for the movable properties (annotated with "PlanningVariable").
Thanks for @Lukáš Petrovický as his comment helped me do the correct investigation!

Comment: An empty entity list is unfortunately a valid case. Solving that just returns immediately, without changing the solution. In some automated cases, that run every day, it can happen that some days there are no entities to assign. It's like doing `Collections.reverse()` on an empty list - that too doesn't fail fast either.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I checked your profile, thank you for this awesome piece of software! I understand your point, so maybe adding small note in the (well described) example may help the newbies like me avoid this issue. Also there is something else might be needed, it's that the EasyScoreCalculator (I didn't test yet the constraint provider approach) should be in it's own namespace, because when it was in solver namespace the project refused to build because it was seeing 2 EasyScoreCalculator classes, It might be bug I'll try to investigate this more later but if not, it's worth mentioning this

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I looked through the quickstart docs to see if it makes sense to somewhere add "make sure your lesson list isn't empty". It does already say "A `lessonList` field with all lessons". However, there's a trade-off to adding that sentence: the quickstart docs also need to be concise - so adding all such pitfalls notes is counter-productive. For now, for this reason, I'll leave it out, but if more people run into this issue, we can reconsider. Thanks for reporting in any case :)